# URL re-write not working with my Apache using PHP Slim Framework?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, slim

Ok, I am not sure if this is me but I have just come across the Slim framework for PHP which looks very simple and easy to round about better apps with. I am sure its my .htaccess file and I am not sure what the hell I am doing wrong.

So this works with Slim :

```
  http://testvm/index.php/hello/4412
```

But this

```
   http://testvm/hello/4412
```

Gives me a not found error, from Apache,

This

```
   http://testvm/
```

returns a 404 error from Slim (or at lest I think its a 404 from slim).

This might be a better question for Server Fault but it could be the way I have set up Slim, I am very new to this and to PHP Composer, which I used to install Slim.

This is my index.php file

```
        <!doctype html><html>
        <head><meta charset="utf-8"><title>Untitled Document</title></head> <body>
        <?php
            require 'vendor/autoload.php';

            $app = new \Slim\Slim();

            $app->get('/hello/:name', function ($name) {
                    echo "Hello, $name";
            });

            $app->run();
       ?>
       </body></html>
```

This is my current .htaccess file

```
       Options +FollowSymLinks
       RewriteEngine On
       RewriteBase /

       RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
       RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
       RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
       #RewriteRule    ^$ /testvm/index.php/  [L]
       #RewriteRule    (.*) /testvm/index.php/$ [L]
```

If I uncomment the bottom two rules I get a server 500 error?

I have already tried

```
         RewriteEngine On
         RewriteBase /my_app/

         RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
         RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

This makes "/testvm/index.php/hello/XXXX" work but I want it to work without any index.php file within the URL? I am sure this has to be something to do with my .htaccess files.

Now I am running this within a VM (Virtual Machine) which is Ubuntu 13.04, which has been fully updated just not to 13.10 let. I have checked and the rewrite.load is listed within the modes-enable folder in my apache build on this VM.

So what I am doing wrong?

All help some welcome. :)

Glenn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this rule in `DOCUMENT_ROOT/testvm/.htaccess` file:

```
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteBase /

   RewriteRule ^$ /testvm/index.php  [L]

   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteRule ^testvm/((?!index\.php/).+)$ /testvm/index.php/$1 [L,NC]
```

Comment: Just try this, but it also gives me a 500 server error, does this mean the the mod rewrite to not working right? Should I uninstall Apache and try Nginx? Also /testvm/ is just the web pointer, it loads what is saved to the /var/www path, so my .htaccess file is in the doc root or I am not understanding that right?

Comment: ok try edited code and if it gives 500 you need to check your Apache error.log

Comment: Just tried your edits but its just coming back with a 404 error from Apache and not Slim.

Comment: Just for testing try: `RewriteRule ^testvm/((?!index\.php/).+)$ /testvm/index.php/$1 [L,NC,R]`

Comment: Sorry Nope, I am thinking this might have something to do with my Apache install, I might build a clean new build and install Nginx to see if its easyer

Answer (score 0):

I have markered your answer has right because you gave me lots of help and I have got it to work, with the follow code,

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php [QSA]
```

so now if I go to testvm/ i get a slim 404 error and when loading testvm/hello/TESTNAMEEXAMPLE it loads.

Hope my code above will help someone else about.

Glenn.